# AngularFire updating only once

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

Why is AngularFire updating the database just once ?

I'm getting the user as this:

```
var firebaseURL = "https://..";

angularFire(new Firebase(firebaseURL), $scope, "database").then(function() {
    $scope.user = $scope.database.users[0];
});
```

And in the view:

```
<input ng-model="user.name" />
```

When I'm changing the input, it only updates once then never does.

Also, if I change something by using the firebase ui, the model does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `angularFire` function in a promise context, the continuation (the `then` clause) is run only once and for the initial data. From [the docs](http://angularfire.com/documentation.html):

> Data from Firebase is loaded asynchronously, you can use the promise to be notified when initial data from the server has loaded.

I suspect you want something of this kind:

```js
angularFire(new Firebase(firebaseURL), $scope, "database");
$scope.$watch("database[0]", function (newVal) {
    $scope.user = newVal;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I found this solution earlier, implemented it and it works.